# fails fetching XML data from multiple url in one shot

Tags: php, mysql, xml, url

my code looks like this

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
include 'date.php';

function fetch_url_content()
{
    $conn = get_dbConnection();

    $fp = fopen("abc.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $count = 0;
    while (!feof($fp))
    {

    $url = fgets($fp);

    //read feed into SimpleXML object
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);


    foreach($sxml->channel->item as $type){
    $description = $type->description;
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($description);
    $a=array();

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node){
    array_push($a,$node->nodeValue);
    }
    $a1 = $type->title;
    $a2 = addslashes($a[3]);
    $a3 = $a[5];
    $a4 = date_correction('30-'.$a[1]); 

    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO   my_table(`c1`,`c2`,`c3`,`c4`) 
    VALUES ($a1,'$a2',$a3,'$a4')";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();

    $count++;
        }
    }
    echo "successfully inserted ".$count." entries to the DB";  
}
fetch_url_content();
?>
```

my abc.txt file looks something like this

```
http://example.com/RssNAV.aspx?swise=y&mf=43
http://example.com/RssNAV.aspx?swise=y&mf=36
http://example.com/RssNAV.aspx?swise=y&mf=4
http://example.com/RssNAV.aspx?swise=y&mf=62
```

here in the above code im trying to take take the first url process it,insert the data to DB and do the same to second third and so on.

but here my code is working fine only for the last url if i change the order of the url's in abc.txt it work fine only for the last url and gives the following error to other url's

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://example.com/RssNAV.aspx?swise=y&mf=43%0D%0A:4: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\v\xml\fetch_xml_data.php on line 21

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): <body> in C:\xampp\htdocs\v\xml\fetch_xml_data.php on line 21
```

what should be the modification to resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

This could be a result of the line endings in your abc.txt file.
If the file has Windows new line characters, try saving it with Unix new line characters.
If that isn't possible you could replace your fgets() solution with something like this:

```
$file = fopen("abc.txt,"r");
$text = fread($file, filesize("abc.txt"));
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: thank you @scott anderson your answer almost worked but it used to take an empty line at the end so instead i tried  $url = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', fgets($fp)); and it worked fine.